# image responsiveness for several devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my html code :

```
<picture>
<source srcset="480_smaller_landscape.jpg" media="(max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)">
<source srcset="776_smaller_portrait.jpg" media="(max-width: 776px) and (orientation: portrait)">
<source srcset="1080_default_landscape.jpg" media="(min-width: 1080px) and (orientation: landscape)">
<source srcset="1926_default_portrait.jpg" media="(min-width: 1926px) and (orientation: portrait)">
<img srcset="default_landscape.jpg" alt="My default image">
</picture>
```

My question is:
if i use this code for image responsive for several devices..

**how many requestes it sents at once? for all images at all or only for image we need for a particular devices...?**

Example : if i load this image page for tablet (776px) then only "776_smaller_portrait.jpg" will be load.

OR

all image will be load at once but only show "776_smaller_portrait.jpg"

What i want to do :

I want to show a particular image for a particular devices and image will be in-line like

```
<img srcset="file_path/device_resulation_image_name.jpg" alt="My default image">
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy enough to test by simply having your developer tools open and set on the Network tab when you load up the page.

```html
<picture>
<source srcset="480_smaller_landscape.jpg" media="(max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)">
<source srcset="776_smaller_portrait.jpg" media="(max-width: 776px) and (orientation: portrait)">
<source srcset="1080_default_landscape.jpg" media="(min-width: 1080px) and (orientation: landscape)">
<source srcset="1926_default_portrait.jpg" media="(min-width: 1926px) and (orientation: portrait)">
<img srcset="default_landscape.jpg" alt="My default image">
</picture>
```

[image]

But, the better approach would be to use CSS Media Queries so that your HTML doesn't become cluttered with stylistic content.  In that case, you'd have one element (maybe a `div`) and use the media query to conditionally set the `background:url()` property for the element. Here's a simple example of that. Run this snippet and resize your browser from large to small and back again.

```css
#responsive { background-size:contain; }

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  #responsive {
    background-image: url("https://free.clipartof.com/10-Free-Smiley-Face-With-Black-Eye.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:801px) {
  #responsive {
    background-image:url("https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/736026129/e17c5fe0e78bd561ba719c2a38ad85b6?v=1");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="responsive"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. when i use this "picture" tag all source will be load at a time..or a particular image for respective device..?

Comment: @Masud001 Did you even read my answer and look at the image I posted within it?

Comment: I have read it..but all image i want to use within html not as a background image...

Comment: @Masud001 Again, read the answer. It's quite clear in showing you that your current code will only cause the single image that meets the device size to be downloaded. The last part isn't suggesting a background image for the page, it's suggesting a background image for an element in the foreground. It makes that element act as a picture frame and is quite common.